Getting SL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK error when trying to do composer install/update
I want to install datadog/dd-trace in order to instrument my CORE php applicarion with datadog APM.
But if I do composer update, it throws "Failed to download datadog/dd-trace from dist: curl error 60 while downloading https://api.github.com/repos/DataDog/dd-trace-php/zipball/c582c9f08eeeb9dcfb650b656adbe699600059d0: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
Now trying to download from source"
this is composer-lock.json
{
    "_readme": [
        "This file locks the dependencies of your project to a known state",
        "Read more about it at https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies",
        "This file is @generated automatically"
    ],
    "content-hash": "c553c8ac36c2b8192fcc4c62a2554664",
    "packages": [
        {
            "name": "datadog/dd-trace",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-php.git",
                "reference": "c582c9f08eeeb9dcfb650b656adbe699600059d0"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DataDog/dd-trace-php/zipball/c582c9f08eeeb9dcfb650b656adbe699600059d0",
                "reference": "c582c9f08eeeb9dcfb650b656adbe699600059d0",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "ext-curl": "*",
                "ext-json": "*",
                "php": "^7.0 || ^8.0.0"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "ext-posix": "*",
                "g1a/composer-test-scenarios": "~3.0",
                "mockery/mockery": "*",
                "phpunit/phpunit": "<10",
                "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.3.0",
                "symfony/process": "<5"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "extra": {
                "scenarios": {
                    "opentelemetry1": {
                        "require": {
                            "open-telemetry/sdk": "@stable",
                            "open-telemetry/extension-propagator-b3": "@stable",
                            "open-telemetry/opentelemetry-logger-monolog": "@stable"
                        },
                        "scenario-options": {
                            "create-lockfile": false
                        }
                    },
                    "opentracing_beta5": {
                        "require": {
                            "opentracing/opentracing": "1.0.0-beta5"
                        },
                        "scenario-options": {
                            "create-lockfile": false
                        }
                    },
                    "opentracing_beta6": {
                        "require": {
                            "opentracing/opentracing": "1.0.0-beta6"
                        },
                        "scenario-options": {
                            "create-lockfile": false
                        }
                    },
                    "opentracing10": {
                        "require": {
                            "opentracing/opentracing": "^1.0"
                        },
                        "scenario-options": {
                            "create-lockfile": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "scenario-options": {
                    "dependency-licenses": false
                }
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "DDTrace\\": "./src/api/"
                }
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "BSD-3-Clause"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "José Carlos Chávez",
                    "email": "jcchavezs@gmail.com"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DataDog",
                    "email": "dev@datadoghq.com",
                    "role": "Developer"
                }
            ],
            "description": "PHP APM Client",
            "keywords": [
                "DataDog",
                "php",
                "tracing"
            ],
            "support": {
                "issues": "https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-php/issues",
                "source": "https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-php/tree/1.0.0"
            },
            "time": "2024-06-04T10:39:22+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "packages-dev": [],
    "aliases": [],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "stability-flags": [],
    "prefer-stable": false,
    "prefer-lowest": false,
    "platform": [],
    "platform-dev": [],
    "plugin-api-version": "2.6.0"
}```



I tried by providing my personal access token, also downloading latest cacert.pem and referring to it in php.ini, updating composer, disabling SSL verification.

